# Selecting specific tables from sqlite3 database using Python

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a ~1 GB sqlite databse with around 250,000 tables. I need to access the data of a few specific tables which their names start with a pattern *e.g.* 'ABC'.

I'm using this line of code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'ABC%'")
```

This works fine but very slow. It takes around 1 minute to select those tables. Is there any way to speed up this query? Thank you

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity, what kind of application is it that ends up using 250,000 tables?

Comment: @jpw to analyze large datasets. I have large amount of CSV files that need to be imported to a single db.